# Creating application data during setup

Tags: wix

What's the best way to create a folder for my application in application data (All Users/AppData or ProgramData depending on OS) during setup?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder" Name="CommonAppData">
  <!-- your subdir structure here -->
</Directory>
```

Use the `CommonAppDataFolder` property get a reference to the currect directory ( OS specific )  and then nest `Directory` elements along with a `Component` element and `CreateFolder` element to get the directory built out.

Also be aware of the default folder permissions of this part of the filesystem and compare it against your expectations.